# Algorithm for the resolvent of a matrix, and LUBackSubstitution

Tags: matrix, numerics, linear-algebra

Suppose `A` is a complex `n x n` matrix where `n` is quite big, given as a numeric array. For many values of the complex number `z`, and many complex vectors `b` with `n` components, I need to compute `LinearSolve[A-z*IdentityMatrix[n],b]`. But calling `LinearSolve` repeatedly is slow, and I need something faster. Note that the matrix `Inverse[A-z*IdentityMatrix[n]]` is also known as the resolvent of `A`.

In my application, `A` is not diagonalizable, so I cannot make an eigendecomposition. But I can always assume that `z` is not an eigenvalue of `A`. I think a reasonable algorithm is to use a Schur decomposition as a pre-processing step, and to perform a backsubstitution each time the resolvent is applied:

```
(* random example *)
n = 2000;
A = RandomComplex[{-1-I,1+I},{n,n}];

(* slow implementation *)
resolventSlow[z_,b_] := LinearSolve[A-z*IdentityMatrix[n],b];

(* preprocessing *)
{Q,T} = SchurDecomposition[A,RealBlockDiagonalForm->False];

(* faster implementation *)
resolventFast[z_,b_] := Q.LUBackSubstitution[{T-z*IdentityMatrix[n],Range[1,n],1.},Conjugate[Conjugate[b].Q]];

(* timing *)
z = RandomComplex[{-1-I,1+I}];
b = RandomComplex[{-1-I,1+I},n];
RepeatedTiming[x1 = resolventSlow[z,b];] (* about 0.5 seconds *)
RepeatedTiming[x2 = resolventFast[z,b];] (* about 0.1 seconds *)
Chop[Norm[x1-x2]] (* zero as expected *)
```

The function `LUBackSubstitution` that I use for backsubstitution has been obsolete since 2003, and its specification is a little arcane. See for example [this v4 documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v4/MainBook/3.7.8.html) and [this documentation of LUDecomposition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LUDecomposition.html).

**Question:** Is there an idiomatic replacement for `LUBackSubstitution` in the code above, that does not explicitly invoke obsolete symbols or low-level libraries such as BLAS? Alternatively, is there another useful algorithm for the resolvent that I could use instead?

Comment: It might be fast to create a `LinearSolveFunction` using `LinearSolve[T-z*IdentityMatrix[n]]` since `T` is already upper triangular.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just tried `Q.LinearSolve[T-z*IdentityMatrix[n]][Conjugate[Conjugate[b].Q]]` and it is about as fast as `LinearSolve[A-z*IdentityMatrix[n],b]` in the example above, so about a factor of 5 away from the algorithm that calls `LUBackSubstitution`.

Comment: Ouch. Yes, I had to see for myself after you noted this, and that is pretty bad. I do not have an alternative to propose though. That stated, I don't think `LUBackSubstitution` is going anywhere so it should be safe to use, deprecation notwithstanding.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Just wanted to add that in `resolventFast`, I think about half the time is spent allocating `T-z*IdentityMatrix[n]`, but for the moment it if fast enough for me.

Comment: It's unfortunate that you give the restriction "does not explicitly invoke ... low-level libraries such as BLAS"; otherwise: ``{qq, tt} = SchurDecomposition[A, RealBlockDiagonalForm -> False]; resolventFast2[z_, b_] := Module[{tr = tt - z IdentityMatrix[n], bb = b . Conjugate[qq]}, LinearAlgebra`BLAS`TRSV["U", "N", "N", tr, bb]; qq . bb]``

Comment: Thank you very much, your `TRSV` code works for me and is about as fast as the `LUBackSubstitution` code. I explicitly excluded BLAS since I was hoping there could be, for example, some way to give `LinearSolve` a hint about upper triangularity.

Comment: Version 13.1 now has `UpperTriangularMatrix[]`, which you can try for your resolvent computation.

Comment: I have been too lazy to install 13.1 so far, but based on the documentation of `UpperTriangularMatrix` I think you are right, it will make `LinearSolve` go fast. If you feel like writing a one-sentence answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @J.M., starting with Version 13.1 (June 2022) there is `UpperTriangularMatrix`. It is efficient with `LinearSolve`, see the Details-section of [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpperTriangularMatrix.html).

Therefore one can now use the following idiomatic code:

```
(* V13.1 *)

(* preprocessing *)
{Q,T} = SchurDecomposition[A,RealBlockDiagonalForm->False];

(* new solution *)
resolventFast[z_,b_] := Q.LinearSolve[UpperTriangularMatrix[T-z*IdentityMatrix[n]],
                                      Conjugate[Conjugate[b].Q]];
```

**Possible improvement 1.** To also exploit efficient storage, one could call `T = UpperTriangularMatrix[T]` right after `SchurDecomposition`.

**Possible improvement 2.** Version 13.1 also has `BlockUpperTriangularMatrix` (experimental). If `A` is real then one can use `SchurDecomposition` in default mode which produces a block-upper-triangular `T`, but has the advantage that both `Q` and `T` are real which saves memory:

```
(* V13.1 -- only for real A *)

{Q,T} = SchurDecomposition[A];
resolventFast[z_,b_] := Q.LinearSolve[BlockUpperTriangularMatrix[
                                        T-z*IdentityMatrix[n]],b.Q];
```

Comment: Warning: I have not been able to try any of this, since I am not on V13.1 yet.

Comment: user293787, you can always use the wolfram cloud to try out such things.