# Plotting resolvent of the matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, complex, visualization

I'm trying to reproduce resolvent plot of circulant matrix, page 59 of Mark Embree's [slides](https://cscproxy.mpi-magdeburg.mpg.de/mpcsc/events/trogir/slides/psa_slides.pdf)

[image: plot of matrix resolvent]

Straightforward solution below, relying on  `ComplexPlot3D` is below. It works for some matrices, but for this one it fails. Is there a more robust way to plot the resolvent?

```
n = 5;
A = IdentityMatrix[n];
A = A[[2 ;;]]~Join~{First[A]};
ii = IdentityMatrix[n];
A // MatrixForm
ComplexPlot3D[Norm@Inverse[z*ii - A], {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}]
```

Comment: You can also define `A` like this: `A=RotateLeft[IdentityMatrix[5]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using the default `Norm`:

```
resolvent=Inverse[z*ii-A];
aux[zz_?NumericQ]:=Block[{z=zz},Norm[resolvent]];
Plot3D[aux[x+I*y],{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2},PlotPoints->100]
```

Answer (score 4):

For matrix,maybe use "Frobenius" norm.

```
norm = Norm[Inverse[z*ii - A], "Frobenius"];
Block[{z = x + I*y}, 
 Plot3D[norm, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"Re z", "Im z"}]]
(* ComplexPlot3D[norm, {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}] *)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit wasteful to invert just to take the 2-norm afterwards. Instead, recall that the 2-norm of $\mathbf A^{-1}$ is the reciprocal of the smallest singular value of $\mathbf A$, which is about the same amount of effort as computing the 2-norm (largest singular value) of $\mathbf A$. To accentuate the positions of the singularities (i.e. the eigenvalues), you can then take a logarithm:

```
mat = SparseArray[ToeplitzMatrix[UnitVector[5, 5], UnitVector[5, 2]]];
Plot3D[-Log[First[SingularValueList[SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> x + I y, {5, 5}] - mat,
                                    -1, Tolerance -> 0]]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
       BoxRatios -> Automatic, ClippingStyle -> None, 
       ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors", #3] &)]
```

[image: resolvent of circulant matrix]

(I also use this identity in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136379) involving the $\varepsilon$-pseudospectrum.)

---

It should perhaps also be noted that Embree's example also happens to be the companion matrix of the polynomial $z^5-1$, which should explain why the eigenvalues are arranged that way.

Comment: Since you bring up efficiency: For every [normal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix) `mat` (and OP's matrix is normal) there is an orthonormal basis relative to which it is diagonal and therefore `evals=Eigenvalues[mat]; maxsval[z_]:=Max[Map[1/Abs[z-#]&,evals]]` computes the max singular value of the resolvent, which is hard to beat. What is an efficient algorithm for a non-normal matrix? Perhaps a Schur decomposition (cf. [this question of mine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268786)) would help but I have not thought it through.

Comment: As I recall, Toh and Trefethen had an Arnoldi-based method for matrices that you could use after a preliminary Schur decomposition. I haven't experimented with that approach yet, tho.

Comment: Thanks, [this seems to be the paper you are referring to](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/publication/PDF/1996_65.pdf); will have a look.